# SQL Summarize and Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which I am selecting the following columns

```
Work_Role
Date_Invoice
Bill_Amnt
```

I have multiple work roles invoiced at multiple dates. I would like to summarize this by work role and see the amount billed by year on each column, only 2014 and 2015.

Something like this:

```
Work_Role     Bill_2014     Bill_2015    
P1            xxx,xxx       xxx,xxx   
P3            xxx,xxx       xxx,xxx    
E1            xxx,xxx       xxx,xxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `case` expression to conditionally sum the bill_amnt depending on year:

```
select Work_Role, 
    sum(case when year(date_invoice) = 2014 then bill_amnt end) as "Bill_2014",
    sum(case when year(date_invoice) = 2015 then bill_amnt end) as "Bill_2015"
from your_table
group by Work_Role
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `conditional case expression`:

```
select role,
sum(case when year(bill_date) = 2014 then amount else 0 end),
sum(case when year(bill_date) = 2015 then amount else 0 end)
from table
group by role
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `PIVOT` query:

```
SELECT
  WORK_Role,
  COALESCE(Bill_2014,0) AS Bill_2014,
  COALESCE(Bill_2015,0) AS Bill_2015
FROM (
    SELECT
        Work_Role,
        'Bill_'+str(year(Date_Invoice),4) as [year],
        Bill_Amnt as Amount 
    FROM T
) as T
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR [year] IN (Bill_2014,Bill_2015)
)AS p;
```